# An error occured while starting the kernel spyder 4

Tags: python, anaconda, kernel, spyder, gdal

I'm using python library GDAL for school and i got trouble by running some of my codes, specifically on spyder 4. Every time I got this error message:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback 
functools.partial(.advance_eventloop at 0x000001EDF7A80048>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743, 
in _run_callback
ret = callback()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 
314, in advance_eventloop
eventloop(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py", line 
232, in loop_tk
app.tk.createfilehandler(stream.getsockopt(zmq.FD), READABLE, notifier)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'createfilehandler'
```

I'm actually working with conda (4.8.3) and python 3.6.10.final.0

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274960/an-error-occured-while-starting-the-kernel-spyder-4. There's no fix for it yet, sorry.